# maven2: how do I get/set the location for the local .jar cache?

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm trying to get the [hibernate-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/) project to work. I downloaded it and can run

```
mvn eclipse:clean
```

and

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

like the instructions say. And I can import the project into Eclipse. But when I look at the project in Eclipse, it can't find the jars that Maven has downloaded. **Where does Maven put the .jars?** I don't know where this is, if I knew I could set M2_HOME in eclipse and it would all work.

Comment: As of 2016 Maven support in Eclipse has become so good, that it should be used instead of the eclipse targets from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Linux: /home/<user>/.m2
Windows: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.m2
```

Also, you may want to look into using the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin if you are doing Maven development with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I found it, maven looks in its settings.xml under

```
<settings><localRepository>{PathHere}</localRepository></settings>
```

which if not found, defaults to ~/.m2/repository as Taylor L's answer mentions.